# g++ not storing the header directory with Qt

Tags: qt, g++

Being a beginner at c++ I kindly request your help

I have to work with Qt as I was provided a couple of source files for a school project, but can't manage to build the code with g++ (MinGw-w64).
All the project source files and header files are organized in their respective folders within a workspace folder. Added to that are the headers and source files for Qt that g++ needs to fetch.

In its third line, my main.cpp file calls for the QApplication file with '#include '. In turn, this QApplication calls for other submodules with for example '#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>'.

I first entered this command into the terminal:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

Which obviously led to the following error:

```
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <QApplication>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I then tried the following:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -ID:/QT515/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/include/QtWidgets
```

and got this error:

```
D:\TUM_bureau\Cours\SS_2022\ARL\Group-D-master>g++ -c main.cpp -I D:/QT515/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/include/QtWidgets
In file included from D:/QT515/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from main.cpp:3:
D:/QT515/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43:10: fatal error: QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

It seems that the compiler can find the location of the header file once when it calls main.cpp, but then when another source file is called by the main it forgets where these headers are. Even worse, this qtwidgetsglobal is in the same folder as QApplication so it should have no problem finding it.

Could someone give me any direction please ?

Comment: Note that the compiler isn't looking for `qtwidgetsglobal.h`, it's looking for `QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h` so you need to add something like `-ID:/QT515/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt5_design_studio_reduced_version/include` to your compile command.  Having said that, how are you building this?  Manually?  Using [`qmake`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-manual.html) should make all of this a lot easier.

Comment: Try `qmake -project` in the directory with main.cpp in it to create a project file, and then `qmake` (or open the .pro in Qt Creator, if you're using that).

Comment: I tried the first option and it seems to resolve the issue explained in the original post, I still have issues but it only a matter of adding all the possible paths. I also tried using qmake but I think it is not installed on my computer, or the installation was corrupted as it cannot be found when I call it. Thank you for your answers !